# How do I use the apply function to target specific dimensions in an array?

Tags: r, arrays, apply

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Fill a four-dimensional array of dimensions 2, 4, 3, 3 with a regular sequence. Using the function apply, return the sum of the elements of the matrices contained in the first two dimensions (you should obtain a 2 × 2 matrix).

I came up with the following:

```
a<-array(1:10,c(2,4,3,3))
apply(a,c(1,2),sum)
```

But I receive the following result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   47   45   43   41
[2,]   56   54   52   50
```

Am I misunderstanding the question? How do I get a 2x2 matrix in this situation?

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: It is difficult to answer without an expected output.  May be `matrix( apply(a, 2, sum), 2, 2)`

Comment: Is it possible that you shouldn't actually obtain a 2x2 matrix (ie, there's typo in the homework)?  It seems like you should either get a 2x4 matrix or a 3x3 matrix (depending on how you interpret the question).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no expected output. I am working through a textbook on geometric morphometrics in R, and there is no answer key. The title of the question is "manipulating array and matrix objects".

Comment: With a starting matrix of 2x4x3x3, how is any summary (that reduces to a length of 1) supposed to attain 2x2? Are you certain it's `sum`? I can see `apply(a, 1, range)` producing 2x2, but not `sum`.

Comment: I am certain. I directly copied the question from the textbook. I may have to write an email to the author to figure out what is actually being asked.